# UITableViewCell subview animation affects multiple cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, ios8, core-animation

I have a UITableView with custom UITableViewCells. I put an animation in didSelectRow for one view in the cell to hide and the other to show. When I do this though it affects other cells as in the animation happens to other cells as well.

For example if I have 20 cells, and I select cell at indexPath 1, the animation happens at indexPath 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16 and 19.

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"moveCell" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:animationFlipTime];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:cell cache:NO];
[cell.view1 setHidden:NO];
[cell.view2 setHidden:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I have also tried other animation methods like `[UIView animateWithDuration...]` and they all render the same result.

Help?

Comment: The problem happens only when you scroll, right? Other words, if you don't, only one cell animates?

Comment: Do you see the animation happen for all those cells, or do you find that they have changed when you scroll down?

Comment: Not sure, the other cells are out of the tableView frame so I have to scroll to see them but not sure if this triggers it.

Comment: Yes, I suspect it is the scrolling that causes it.  Cells are reused when they scroll off screen, so you need to amend your cellForRowAtIndexPath to reset them.

Comment: Or you can implement `prepareForReuse` in your custom subclass of UITableViewCell and reset the subviews there.